# Oracle: how to disable table compression on dmp file import

Tags: oracle, import

I have dmp file that was created by EXP utility. The source database has table compression enabled.  How can I  disable compression while importing dmp file. The destination database does not have this future enabled.

I can not find any switches on IMP  utility for this purpose.

```
imp u/p@sid file=test.dmp LOG=test.log  IGNORE=Y TABLES=(A_TABLE) FROMUSER=USR1 TOUSER=USR2
```

here is the error that I'm getting:

```
ORA-00439: feature not enabled: Table compression
```

Both databases are Oracle v 11g.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll have to precreate your tables by using dbms_metadata to extract the definitions from the source database.

You could also use the imp indexfile option to create an editable script in which COMPRESS could be globally replaced with NOCOMPRESS.

Datapump might have an option for doing this ... in 11g I'd be using datapump instead of imp/exp anyway.

Comment: thanks for reply. I have the script to recreate tables. My only problem is to load data from dmp file. 
Normally I use datapump. But this time one table was giving me so much problems (ORA-39014, ORA-04030) , that I've decided to try old import/export utilities.

Comment: If you precreate the tables, then IMP with IGNORE=Y will just import the data from the export file

Comment: @Gary. That is what I'm doing and I'm  getting "ORA-00439: feature not enabled: Table compression".

Comment: So your table is precreated, using NOCOMPRESS, and IGNORE=Y, but you still get that error? Is it possible to tell whether the error is occuring as part of the attempt to create the table? I wonder whether the attempt to create the table is raising this error but IGNORE=Y is only set to ignore "Table already exists" errors, and is not ignoring "Feature not enabled" errors. One option would be to open the exp file and replace `COMPRESS` with `NOCOMPRESS` (try to modify a string of a given length to one of the same length to avoid rewriting all the subsequent data though)

Comment: @David. You were right. Precreating tables  and using **IGNORE=Y** should work. It does not work in my case  because the table that I'm trying to import contains custom types. I missed the warning:

"IMP-00063: Warning: Skipping table "USR12"."A_TABLE" because object type "USR2"."CUST_TYPE1" cannot be created or has different identifier"